# How to iterate a dataset several times using TensorFlow's Dataset API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

How to output the value in a dataset several times? (dataset is created by Dataset API of TensorFlow)

```py
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(100)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
sess = tf.Session()
epoch = 10

for i in range(epoch):
   for j in range(100):
      value = sess.run(next_element)
      assert j == value
      print(j)
```

Error message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[]], output_types=[DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 25):

First of all I advice you to read [Data Set Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets). There is described all the details of DataSet API.

Your question is about iterating over the data several times. Here are two solutions for that:

1. Iterating all epochs at once, no information about end of individual epochs

```py
import tensorflow as tf

epoch   = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
dataset = dataset.repeat(epoch)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
sess = tf.Session()

num_batch = 0
j = 0
while True:
    try:
        value = sess.run(next_element)
        assert j == value
        j += 1
        num_batch += 1
        if j > 99: # new epoch
            j = 0
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break

print ("Num Batch: ", num_batch)
```

2. Second option inform you about ending each of epoch, so you can ex. check validation loss:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

epoch = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
sess = tf.Session()

num_batch = 0

for e in range(epoch):
    print ("Epoch: ", e)
    j = 0
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            value = sess.run(next_element)
            assert j == value
            j += 1
            num_batch += 1
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break

print ("Num Batch: ", num_batch)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your tensorflow version is 1.3+, I recommend the high-level API `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`. The `sess` created by this API can automatically detect `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` with `sess.should_stop()`. For most of training situations, you need to shuffle data and get a batch each step, I have added these in the following code.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

epoch = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100) # comment this line if you don't want to shuffle data
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=32)     # batch_size=1 if you want to get only one element per step
dataset = dataset.repeat(epoch)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

num_batch = 0
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() as sess:
    while not sess.should_stop():
        value = sess.run(next_element)
        num_batch += 1
        print("Num Batch: ", num_batch)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```py
while True:
  try:
    print(sess.run(value))
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    break
```

Whenever the dataset iterator reaches the end of the data, it will raise tf.errors.OutOfRangeError, you can catch it with except and start the dataset from the beginning.

Comment: You should explain your code or include comments as well

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Toms answer, for tensorflow 2+, you can use the following high-level API calls (the code proposed in his answer is deprecated in tensorflow 2+):

```
epoch = 10
batch_size = 32
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100) 

dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100) # comment this line if you don't want to shuffle data
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat(epoch)

num_batch = 0
for batch in dataset:
        num_batch += 1
        print("Num Batch: ", num_batch)
```

A helpful call to track progress is the total number of batches that will be iterated over (to be used **after** the `batch` and the `repeat` calls):

```
num_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset)
```

Note that currently (tensorflow 2.1), the `cardinality` method is still experimental.