# What's the difference between the print inside and outside

Tags: python, macos, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am learning the tensorflow which version is 2.8.0 on my MacBook M1.
For debugging the code in the map function of dataset, I want to print tensor value in my function.

```
def function(i):
    print("in: ", i)
    if i < 2:
        i = i - 1
    return i


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 6)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(function, inp=[x], Tout=tf.int64))
for x in dataset:
    print("out:", x)
```

I got the output as blew:

```
in:  tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
out: tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64)
in:  tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
out: tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
in:  tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64)
out: tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64)
in:  tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64)
out: tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64)
in:  tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64)
out: tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

After I delete the print outside, I did not get any output.
What's the difference between the print inside and the print outside.
I don't understand why it can only take effect when the prints appear at the same time.
Beside that, what the difference between print and tf.print?

Comment: Careful when using expressions like `if i < 2:`.  It runs here ok because you end up passing single element Tensors (shape ()).  But if `i` had more than one element, I expect an "ambiguity" error.  That's what you'd get from an array or Series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because tensorflow datasets have *lazy loading*, which means they aren't evaluated until you actually try to iterate over the result.

When you removed the for loop, you were no longer iterating over the result, so it was never evaluated.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679387/494134

Comment: Thanks! It seems difficult to debug tensor value.Which way I can use to debug conveniently?@John Gordon

Comment: @ge1mina023 If you want an easy way to avoid the lazy loading, you can just wrap the call in `list()`, which will force evaluation.  `dataset = list(dataset.map(...))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice.Because of large dataset, which way I can exploit for executing print() only once rather than waiting for a long time to get all print() 's output?